# Symfony/Doctrine ambiguity's regarding to ArrayCollection usage

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

I have two approaches and I need your expertise on the matter...
Let's say we call a certain API and store every request data into `RequestEntity`. And let's say that API call we made initiates some long-run process on a remote server. So as to have an update of the state of this particular process we have to call every second API and store a response into $logEntries which is ArrayCollection:

```
class RequestEntity implements PlatformRequestInterface 
{
     ...

     /**
      * @var RequestLogEntity[]|ArrayCollection
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=RequestLogEntity::class, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", 
      *  mappedBy="request")
      */
     protected $logEntries;

     ...

     public function __construct(...) 
     {
          $this->logEntries = [];
     }

     ...

     /**
     * @return RequestLogEntity[]|ArrayCollection
     */
     public function getLogEntries()
     {
         return $this->logEntries;
     }

     ...
}

class RequestLogEntity 
{
    ...
 
   /**
    * @var RequestEntity
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=RequestEntity::class, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", 
    * inversedBy="logEntries")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="request_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
   protected $request;
 
   ...
 
  /**
   * Gets a current request to work with
   *
   * @return RequestEntity
  */
  public function getRequest()
  {
      return $this->request;
  }
 
...
}
```

Let's assume that we have `RequestEntity` with `ID` 42 that has in $logEntities 5 records:
[image]

So every process on the remote server has its own velocity and some processes can stack for a while in a particular stage which creates an enormous amount of `RequestLogEntity` records with an identical data since we are calling for an update every second.

So approach 1 is we can just retrieve existed $logEntities in `RequestEntity`, loop through them(max amount is 10), checking data, and if we've already got a record with a similar data we just update `created_at` field in a record therefore avoid a necessity to insert a new record every time, creating a huge stack of a similarity:

```
private function loggingResponseMessageToRequest(
    RequestProgress $progress,
    RequestEntity $request
) {
    foreach ($request->getLogEntries() as $log) {
        if (
            $log->getRequest()->getId() == $progress->getRequestId()
            && $log->getMessage() == $progress->getMessage()
        ) {
            $log->setCreatedAt($progress->getCreatedAt());
            $this->entityManager->persist($log);
            $this->entityManager->flush($log);

            return;
        }
    }
 
...
}
```

Another approach on the other hand is we can reach out directly for `RequestLogEntity` using obviously `entityManager` and search for that particular record in DB. If we do have the one we update `created_at` and `persists()` and `flush()` $requestLogEntity. If we do not have a record we proceed with `INSERT` procedure further:

```
 private function loggingResponseMessageToRequest(
    RequestProgress $progress,
    RequestEntity $request
) {
    $requestLogEntity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(RequestLogEntity::class)
        ->findOneBy([
            'request_id' => $progress->getRequestId(), //12345
            'message' => $progress->getMessage() // 'Test1'
        ]);

    if ($requestLogEntity) {
        $requestLogEntity->setCreatedAt($progress->getCreatedAt());
        $this->entityManager->persist();
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return;
    }

...
```

So what do you think? What approach has more Symfony way in this particular case and why? Would very much appreciate your honesty! And many thanks in advance...